# bigquery partition_expiration_days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to know the comportment of partition_expiration_days for **NULL** partition.

I created a partioned table like this :

```
table name : containers
columns: valid_to,
type : date,
...
```

the expirations day is 3(partition_expiration_days=3)

My question is
a row having with null value in the col valid_to will be remove in the futur or no ?

The comportment of partition_expiration_days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation doesn't give information on the partition expiration for `NULL` value in partitioned date column :

[Managing partitioned tables BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables)

I think in this case, the `NULL` partition cannot be deleted automatically with the partition expiration.

You have to delete it manually with a `SQL` query.